# This is question about integration. I want you to check error.

Tags: integration

[image: This is the question]

![This is the solution that I tried, but the answer is wrong. I cannot find any
mistakes, or did I approach this problem to the wrong way?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgxFP.jpg)

Please tell me which part is wrong, or if there are better solution, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: See http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ11/integ11.html

Comment: Thank you. Address that you gave me can help me to get an answer, but I want to prove it, not only an answer. You know, that is the way we learn math.

Comment: Since you know you have the wrong answer, you can retry the integral and see if you arrive at the correct answer. You know, that is also a way we learn math.

Comment: I would say that the error will be somewhere in the last two rows. There is somehow not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am almost blind, I cannot read your notes. So, I propose something.

Let us consider first $$I=\int \sqrt{x^2+a^2} dx$$ Change variable using $x=a\sinh(y)$, so $dx=a \cosh(y)dy$ and then $$I=a^2\int \cosh^2(y)dy$$ Now, use $$\cosh(2y)=2\cosh^2(y)-1$$ So, $$I=\frac{a^2}{2} \int\Big(1+\cosh(2y)\Big)dy=\frac{a^2}{2}\Big(y+\frac{1}{2}\sinh(2y)\Big)=\frac{a^2}{2}  \Big(y+\sinh (y) \cosh (y)\Big)$$ and you need now to integrate for $y$ between $0$ and $\sinh^{-1}(1)$. So, the result is $$\frac{a^2}{2}  \left(\sqrt{2}+\sinh ^{-1}(1)\right)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Wow ! This is the proof what I want. Thanks for your proof. I understood :)